# ORACLE SQL Select only MAX of each group by number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with selecting sum of balances for specific Acc, Nam for a given period.

```
SELECT Acc, Nam, SUM(Bal) FROM table WHERE
MAX(Par) = (SELECT Par WHERE Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat >1105 AND Dat <1405)
AND Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat >1105 AND Dat <1405
GROUP BY Acc, Nam


Acc --- Nam --- Bal --- Par --- Dat
101 --- One --- 150 --- 131 --- 1205
101 --- One --- 120 --- 132 --- 1205
101 --- One --- 160 --- 133 --- 1305
102 --- Two --- 190 --- 121 --- 1205
102 --- Two --- 110 --- 122 --- 1305
102 --- Two --- 150 --- 123 --- 1305
```

The final output should be:

```
Acc --- Nam --- Bal
101 --- One --- 280
102 --- Two --- 340
```

So it will sum of all balances within the period separated by Account and Account Name. Only balances with the highest Par number per day should sum in total. Please advise.

UPDATE

I did it with below row_number method but what i received is just the total of all rows (without some of them). Below is the code which is showing: two accounts, two account descriptions, parameters, dates and balance. I would like to see two lines which will be the sum of all dates in a range for given account with the highest parameter number in a separate day. Final output shoul be only three columns: account, name and balance. This query should be able to chose max parameter of each day and sum all of these max values to one account.

```
 SELECT h.account, h.name, h.paramet, h.date, h.balance 
    FROM h
    WHERE TRUNC(h.date) > '01-Jun-16' AND TRUNC(h.date) < '10-Jun-16' 
    AND h.account IN ('410212','410213') 
    AND h.fund LIKE 'SSPSP
```

Comment: Are you saying this does not work:
SELECT Acc, Nam, SUM(Bal) FROM table WHERE
Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat >1105 AND Dat <1405
GROUP BY Acc, Nam

Comment: MAX() cannot go in WHERE statements but you can put it in HAVING clause which is determined after the grouping and aggregation.  Next (SELECT Par WHERE Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat >1105 AND Dat <1405) isn't even valid as their is no table or anythign identified.  So The query you posted wouldn't even give you the results you are showing

Comment: @Matt Input query should be: ` SELECT h.account, h.name, h.paramet, h.date, h.balance 
    FROM h
    WHERE TRUNC(h.date) > '01-Jun-16' AND TRUNC(h.date) < '10-Jun-16' 
    AND h.account IN ('410212','410213') 
    AND h.fund LIKE 'SSPSP`

Comment: @JayKumarR It is showing row with max parameter per whole period - not for each day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
SELECT Acc, Nam, SUM(Bal)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acc, Nam, Dat ORDER BY Par DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t
      WHERE Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat > 1105 AND Dat < 1405
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY Acc, Nam;
```

Comment: can't edit this to remove the duplicate FROM as the edit is <6 characters, but it's there twice

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thank you, but this query is showing sum of almost all rows but not sum of rows with max parameter for each day within the same account.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have checked it once again - i forgot about TRUNC in Dat field after PARTITION BY so there was time also included. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have next question related to above query. How can I create one table with two SUM(Bal) columns with different Date for each other:

Acc --- Nam --- Bal(Dat1) -- Bal(Dat2)
101 --- One ------- 280 ---------- 300
102 --- Two ------- 340 ---------- 180

```
SELECT Acc, Nam, SUM(Bal)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acc, Nam, TRUNC(Dat) ORDER BY Par DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t
      WHERE Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat = 1105 
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY Acc, Nam;

SELECT Acc, Nam, SUM(Bal)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acc, Nam, TRUNC(Dat) ORDER BY Par DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t
      WHERE Acc IN (101,102) AND Dat = 1405
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY Acc, Nam;
```